# Azure AKS container logs location in storage account

Tags: azure, kubernetes, logging, azure-aks, monitor

I want to be able to find specific logs from AKS container, that have diagnostic configured for storage account. I'm able to generate this kind of query from log analytics:

```
ContainerLog
| join kind = inner KubePodInventory on $left.ContainerID == $right.CointainerID
| where Namespace == "default" and LogEntry contains "error"
| project TimeGenerated, LogEntry, ContainerName
```

showing me container logs, yet I'm not able to find same output in actual log files, saved in storage account. Shouldn't both reciever services have same logs available? [Here's the list of log types that aks cluster generates.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/monitor-aks#collect-resource-logs)

Here's the output from log analytics query:
[image]

Comment: can you please provide an output of that query and what you are seeing in the storage account?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT I added query output as screenshot above. What I'm seing in storage account is 7 folders (named after log categories) with ton of subfolders and text files, possibly in JSON format. Couldn't find any relevant string from LogEntry column on screenshot in any of those files.

Comment: @lubierzca were you able to find its solution? I am looking for the same. Kindly help

Comment: @Rahul haven't implemented it myself, but I've heard that the solution here is to use Prometheus solution, embedded into Azure Monitor service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/prometheus-metrics-enable?tabs=azure-portal